# Issue selecting dynamically an img to change its source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to change the `src` of an `img` based on a HTML `file input`.

The markup is the following (please note that, for debug i set an id to the second image, the id is "test").

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img class='thumb' src='../images/placeholder.jpg'>
      <div>
        <input type="file" class='file-input' />
        <button class="btn btn-primary editbtn">EDIT</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img id='test' class='thumb' src='../images/placeholder.jpg'>
      <div>
        <input type="file" class='file-input' />
        <button class="btn btn-primary editbtn">EDIT</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img class='thumb' src='../images/placeholder.jpg'>
      <div>
        <input type="file" class='file-input' />
        <button class="btn btn-primary editbtn">EDIT</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img class='thumb' src='../images/placeholder.jpg'>
      <div>
        <input type="file" class='file-input' />
        <button class="btn btn-primary editbtn">EDIT</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And this is the JavaScript code:

```
$(".editbtn").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().find(".file-input").trigger("click");
});

$(".file-input").change(function(event){
  var selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();

  var imgtag = document.getElementById("test");
  imgtag.title = selectedFile.name;

  reader.onload = function(event) {
    imgtag.src = event.target.result;
  };

  reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);
});
```

it works, but it has `var imgtag = document.getElementById("test");` and it does not works if I change that line for this one: `var imgtag = $(this).parent().parent().find(".thumb");`

Maybe that is not the optimal jquery selector, but I think is a correct selector.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `var imgtag = $(this).parent().parent().find(".thumb")`, the `imgtag` variable is a `jquery` object and not a reference to a `DOM` object, thus you can't use `imgtag.src`.

You have two options here:

1. Use the first element inside the jQuery object (which is the reference to the DOM element): `imgtag[0].src = event.target.result`
2. Use the `attr` function of the jQuery's object: `imgtag.attr('src', event.target.result)`

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks for the explanation! I chose option 2.

Comment: Great :) You can use both options (the second option is a bit safer, since if there is no such element, the first option will cause a javascript error).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.parent()`, `.prev()` with `"img"` as parameter to return jQuery object, followed by `[0]` to reference `DOM` element

```
var imgtag = $(this).parent().prev("img")[0];
```

or if `html` tree remains same

```
var imgtag = this.parentElement.previousElementSibling;
```

Note, `imgtag` references `DOM` element, not jQuery object; where `title` and `src` are `DOM` element properties

```
imgtag.title = selectedFile.name;
imgtag.src = event.target.result;
```

```js
$(".editbtn").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().find(".file-input").trigger("click");
});

$(".file-input").change(function(event){
  var selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();

  var imgtag = $(this).parent().prev("img")[0];
  imgtag.title = selectedFile.name;

  reader.onload = function(event) {
    imgtag.src = event.target.result;
  };

  reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img class='thumb' src='../images/placeholder.jpg'>
      <div>
        <input type="file" class='file-input' />
        <button class="btn btn-primary editbtn">EDIT</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img id='test' class='thumb' src='../images/placeholder.jpg'>
      <div>
        <input type="file" class='file-input' />
        <button class="btn btn-primary editbtn">EDIT</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img class='thumb' src='../images/placeholder.jpg'>
      <div>
        <input type="file" class='file-input' />
        <button class="btn btn-primary editbtn">EDIT</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img class='thumb' src='../images/placeholder.jpg'>
      <div>
        <input type="file" class='file-input' />
        <button class="btn btn-primary editbtn">EDIT</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```